# Getting country_code from response in geocoder

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Reading response results from a geocoder service, I get the country code not in the same place. How do I get the country code from the DOM using simple JavaScript code and not using an external JSON library?

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(iplat, iplong);
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                country_code=results[1].address_components[0].short_name;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
          alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                if (results[1]) {
                    for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                    for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

                    if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "country") {
                        //this is the object you are looking for
                        country= results[0].address_components[i];  
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                    }
                     //alert(country.short_name);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Reverse for loop will be even faster, country is always at the end somewhere :) `for (var i = results[0].address_components.length - 1; i>=0; i--){...}`

Answer (score 2):

Each element of the `address_components` array is itself an array that contains a `types` element that is also an array.  You want to find the element of `address_components` that has a `types` array that contains the value "country" as one of its elements.  See the sample JSON response at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ if it's not clear from what I've written.